# One sided limits

Tags: limits

My graph is shown below

[image]

Can someone explain why $\lim_{x \rightarrow 5^-} = 2$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 5^+} = 2$?

Regards

Comment: This is basically the same as [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908098/approaching-from-the-right-and-from-the-left) where you have also not explained what exactly your problem is.

Comment: ask yourself: if you want $y$ to be as close to $2$ as possible, will you be able to find such $x$ on both sides of $5$? If you answered "yes", $2$ is the limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the graph around $x=5$, you see that three things are happening.

First of all, there is a hole in the graph at $x=5$ which means that the function is not continuous.

There is a black dot over $x=5$ at $y=1$ that is $g(5)=1$

As you approach $5$ from either side of $x=5$ the curve approaches the hole at $y=2$, and that is why both one sided limits are $2$

Comment: 'the curve approaches the hole' - isn't it a simple restatement of the fast that LHS=RHS, which, as I believe, is the OP's question

Comment: I still did not get it.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that by the definition of limit we have

$$\forall \varepsilon>0 \quad \exists \delta>0 \quad \text{such that}\quad \color{red}{\forall x\neq5}\quad|x-5|<\delta \implies|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$

therefore it doesn’t matter for the value  of the limit whether or not $f(5)$ exists and, if it exists, what is the value of $f(5)$ or, in other words whether or not the function is continuous at $x=5$, in any case the limit is $2$.